# Using local storage (JavaScript) in a Wix HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, api, storage, velo

I created an HTML element on my Wix page using Google Charts. My webpage visitors need to fill a questionnaire and the idea would be to give them the results via a pie chart. Here is part of the code of my HTML element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels:["Rodeo", "Calypso", "Balthazar", "Luna", "Kiara", "Mistral", "Saya"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [10, 20, 30, 20, 25, 40, 15],
            backgroundColor: ["#f97a03", "#52aff0", "#35a11d", "#f052e4", "#853fc2", "#f0f712", "#092978"],
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});

</script>
```

The code above works great and I can see the chart on the webpage. Now instead of having predetermined data (like 10, 20, 30, 20, 25, 40, 15 above), I would like to use variables whose values are stored in LocalStorage JavaScript (names of variables are the same as per the lables above but with "loc" as a prefix).

I tried:

```
data: [local.getItem("locrodeo"), local.getItem("loccalypso"), 
local.getItem("locsaya"), local.getItem("locbalthazar"),
local.getItem("locluna"), local.getItem("lockiara"), 
local.getItem("locmistral")],
```

But I think APIs don't work with JS under wix HTML component. So I guess I need to send a message from my Page Code to the HTML element with the information in it. Does anyone know how to do that?

From the Wix Help Center, I found that I need to send a message like this:

```
$w("#myHtmlElement").postMessage("Message for HTML Comp");
```

And then I need to write code in my HTML element to receive the info:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data) {
       let receivedData = event.data;
    }
  };

  //...

</script>
```

For clarity, my objective is to have the pie chart showing the values of the variables locrodeo, loccalypso, locsaya, locluna, locbalthazar, locmistral and lockiara (stored in local storage JS).

Answer (score 0):

This example is just about exactly what you want to do: https://www.wix.com/code/home/example/Chart.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much what I want to do, but the example is more sophisticated and I get lost in the code. I see that in the HTML element, they initially leave the datset empty: data: [ ],//start empty. And then they update the data set with a Onmessage:  window.onmessage = function(event){

    if (event.data && Array.isArray(event.data)) {
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = event.data;
      myChart.update();
    }
    else {
      console.log("HTML Code Element received a generic message:");
      console.log(event.data);
   I tried it bu it doesn't work...

Comment: For clarity: what I want to push into the HTML element is an array of variables: var chartdata = [introdeo, intcalypso, intbalthazar, intmistral, intsaya, intluna, intkiara]; where all variables are integers.

Comment: Hi Sam, I managed to get a step further in my project, however I'm now facing another problem which I explain in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292302/chart-js-on-wix-issue-final-result-doesnt-match-data-sent-via-postmessage   If you could have a look that would be great!